# How to meta refresh after all resources were loaded?

Tags: html, redirect, meta-tags

I want to redircet to another page by meta refresh, but only after all resources were loaded. Any ideas how to archive that?

SOLUTION:

I combined both ways, the meta refresh and the jQuery way.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="pos" uri="/WEB-INF/tld/pos.tld" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="template" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1; url=${callback}/" />         
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/pos_js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                window.location = '${callback}';
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

With this way, for me, it is possible to redirect if the document in fully loaded and if JS is deactivated the meta refresh will throw the user to the callback page.

Comment: Does it have to be by meta-refresh ? can't be by other methods ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Loading all stuff on a page and then throwing it all away by going to another page seems rather counter-productive. Maybe there is a more streamlined way of doing what you want.

Comment: I need a blank site where a Website Optimizer Skript is loaded. For A/B-Testing start- and targetpage have to be one the same subdomain, because in the process at some point I redirect to another subdomain, I need this page. Not that fancy, but its the requirement :(

Comment: Would an iFrame be a better option then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this via jQuery using the `$(document).load()` function.

```
$(document).load(function() {
    window.location = 'http://new.url.com';
});
```

Comment: I already tried this at the beginning, but what if JS is deactivated? The process aborts and the user'll see the blank page. I don't care if the google script isn't loaded in these cases, but the user shouldn't recongnize that..

Answer (score 3):

Only `real` way of doing it is:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1500; url=http://www.example.com/" />
```

That will wait 1.5 seconds for the page to load... not ideal, but without JS you'll be lucky!

**edit:** What about an iFramed option?

Comment: I guess the 1.5 seconds should be enough for todays broadband speeds

Comment: You could change it to be longer/shorter by amending the `1500` - but this is a really poor fix and you should look into Cross Site Domain Policies or do this all in iFrames ;)

Comment: The delay is actually specified in *seconds*, not milliseconds. So `1500` is a very long time...